# Invoke custom method on value changed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a way to invoke one time some method on value changed? I created wrapper for bindingHandlers.value that invoke this method:

```
var update = bindingHandlers.value.update;

bindingHandlers.value.update = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, viewModel) {
    var newValue = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var elementValue = ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element);
    var valueHasChanged = (newValue != elementValue);

    update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingAccessor, viewModel);

    if (valueHasChanged) {
        myMethod();
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly when I change some value myMethod is called two times becuase come dependencyObservable is also changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to subscribe to a value changed, you can subscribe to any observable:

```
var viewModel = { property: ko.observable() };

viewModel.property.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    //do stuff
});
```

To subscribe to all properties of an object you could do something like:

```
function subscribeAll(viewModel) {
    for(var propertyName in viewModel) {
        if(viewModel[propertyName].subscribe === 'function') {
            viewModel[propertyName].subscribe(function(newValue) {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have lease calculator that need object with about 20 properties and I would like to pass my viewModel to this calculator as parameter, so I would like to subscribe to most of the properties.

Comment: You can always iterate the properties and each one that is an `observable` or `observableArray` call `subscribe` on (the easy way may just be to test if each property has a `subscribe` function)

Comment: Updated my answer with a `subscribeAll` method, note that it doesn't do deep graphs, just shallow ones.